# How to make a fuction that can sum the Intervals into a nested array?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have an exercise for college and I still cant solve this. (python)

This is my problem:

Write the code of a function called `sumIntervals` which takes a list of spaces and returns the sum of the lengths of the spaces. Caution: Overlapped intervals should only be measured once.

For example:

```
sumIntervals([[1,2], [6, 10], [11, 15]])  # Returns 9

sumIntervals([[1,4], [7, 10], [3, 5]])  # Returns 7

sumIntervals ([[1,5], [10, 20], [1, 6], [16,19], [5,11]])  # Returns 19
```

I've made a part of it but it doesn't work.

Comment: How far have you come?

Comment: I tried to make a loop to count the range in each row and then put it in a new list and finally printing the lenght of the new list but it didnt work.Or  it doesnt for me idk .

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have, what it's producing and what you were expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like so:
Essentially what we're doing here is separating that input list into the different chunks which we store as the `keyIndex` from there on we run another the second for loop just to add the difference of the numbers individually, so `[6,10]` would become `[6,7,8,9]` to represent the difference of 10-6 = 4. Lastly we'll use the `set()` method just to remove any duplicates as you said that you wanted overlapping to be counted only one.

```py
myList = ([[1,5], [10, 20], [1, 6], [16,19], [5,11]])

def sumIntervals(inputList):
    output = []

    for keyIndex in range(len(inputList)):
        for keyDifference in range(inputList[keyIndex][0], inputList[keyIndex][1]):
            output.append(keyDifference)

    output = set(output)
    print(len(output))

sumIntervals(myList)
```

Comment: Yeah no problem, I've just added a bit more detail just in case you had any questions; I also noticed that you are new here so I just wanted to let you know that if this or any answer solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This just lets everyone know that you've found your answer and gives some reputation to both of us. Of course, do let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

```
p = []
s = 0
for i in list1:
    p.append(i[1] - i[0])
set(p)
list(p)
for c in p:
    s = s + c
```

list1 is the list that contains the subintervals and s is the variable that contains the sum

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set (or dict) to handle the main challenge here: to avoid
double-counting caused by overlaps. For example:

```
def sum_intervals(intervals):
    return len(set(
        i
        for a, b in intervals
        for i in range(a, b)
    ))

tests = (
    [[1,2], [6, 10], [11, 15]],
    [[1,4], [7, 10], [3, 5]],
    [[1,5], [10, 20], [1, 6], [16,19], [5,11]],
)

for t in tests:
    print(sum_intervals(t))  # 9  7  19
```